# What is the need for a C_INT fortran type? Are C and Fortran integers so different?

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

If I declare an integer in fortran as:
`INTEGER(C_INT) :: i` then, if I understand correctly, it's safe to be passed to  a C function. Now disregarding the added headache of always declaring integers this way, is there any reasons not to always declare your variables as C-interoperable? Is there any downside to doing so?

Also, in the case of something as simple a an integer, what exactly does the `C_INT` change from a traditional Fortran integer? Are Fortran and C integers actually different?

Comment: May be same in compilers you and I use but some may have c_int match c_long

Comment: But why would the default int size differ between Fortran and C? And I could, perhaps foolishly, compile my c code with a c compiler with one default int size and then, with my fortran compiler, set the default int size to another size. I can't imagine `C_INT` insulates any of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C integer size is usually fixed because the OS is compiled using C and the system bindings are published as C headers. The operating system designers choose one of the common models like [LLP64, LP64, ILP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing?&section=10#64-bit_data_models) (for 64-bit pointer OS's) and the C compilers then follow this choice.

But Fortran compilers are more free. You can set them to a different configuration. Fortran compiler set to use 8-byte default integers and 8-byte default reals are still perfectly standard conforming! (C would be as well but the choice is fixed in the operating system.)

And because the integers in C and in Fortran do not have to match you need a mechanism to *portably* select the C interoperable kind, whatever the default kind is.

This is not just academic. you can find libraries like MKL compiled with 8-byte integers (the ILP64 model, which is not used by common operating systems for C).

So when you call some API, some function whose interface is defined in C, you want to call it properly, not depending on the settings of the Fortran compiler. That is the use case for the C-interoperable types. If a C function requires an `int`, you give it an `integer(c_int)` and you do not care if the Fortran default integer is the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no fundamental downside and on the same compiler there is no fundamental benefit.

Even in icc a long int is different on 32 and 64 bit OS, so you need to know (or define what you want on the c-side of things).

The only one that is clearly 4-bytes is the C_INT32_T, and hence it is that one that I generally use. And it more of a "future proofing" endeavour to use C_INT32_T , to define it as you want it to be in a fixed numbers of bits sizing.

These all give a 4 byte integer on iFort.

```
USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_INT, C_INT32_T
Integer                 :: 
INTEGER(KIND=4)         ::   !"B"  At least on iFort
INTEGER*4                    !"A"  
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT)     ::
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT32_T) ::   !"C"
```

Usually one finds older code with the style of "A".

I routinely use the style of "B", but even though this is a "defacto standard" it is not conforming to "the standard".

Then when I become concerned with portability I run-through and change the "B" style to "C" style and then I have less heartburn considering others who may be later compiling with the gfortran compiler... Or even some other compiler.

The single byte:

```
BYTE                        :: !Good
INTEGER(KIND=1)             ::
INTEGER(KIND=C_SIGNED_CHAR) ::
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT8_T)      :: !Best
```

The two byte:

```
INTEGER(KIND=2)            ::
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT16_T)    :: !Best
INTEGER(KIND=C_SHORT)      ::
```

The 8 byte:

```
INTEGER(KIND=8)            ::
INTEGER(KIND=C_INT64_T)    :: !Best
INTEGER(KIND=C_LONG_LONG)  ::
```

While this looks somewhat fishy... One can also say:

```
LOGICAL(KIND=4)         ::
LOGICAL(KIND=C_INT32_T) :: !Best here may be C_bool and using 1-byte logical in fortran...? Assuming that there is no benefit with the size of the logical being the same as some float vector
LOGICAL(KIND=C_FLOAT)   ::
```

Comment: You don't aleays care about the storage size, that is the point I was trying to make. You often want compatibility with some API.